# Runtime error in Visual Studio C++ debug mode, but not in release; code used to work

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

In summary, I wrote some code. It ran fine in both debug and release mode. I added code. I started getting an error. I commented out the new code. I *continued* to get the same error, even though I was back to what worked. I discovered this bug only cropped up in debug mode - it runs fine in release.

The error I get is:

```
First-chance exception at 0x748F4598 in Speed3Calib1.exe: Microsoft C++  
exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x005EC350.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I stepped through and found the section that gives me trouble (I've added exception handling since I first asked this question). Here is the section that gives me trouble.

```
try {
    calibrateCamera(object_points_vector, test_image_points_vector, test_image.size(), intrinsic,
            distortion_coefficients, rvecs, tvecs, calibration_flags);
}
catch (cv::Exception &e) {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;        
    return 0;
}
```

The new weirdness is that it never goes into the catch block, but still throws up that error.

Since first asking, I stumbled on a box ticked "break on this error when it is thrown". I un-ticked it, and now it runs, but still the exception appears in the output from Debug. I can't figure out why this has just started, or why I can't catch the cv::Exception.

I noted that according to Microsoft, first-chance exceptions appear before the program gets to handle them.

> However, if the application is being debugged, the debugger sees all exceptions before the program does.

I am still confused though: as the execution never went into the catch block, does this mean the first chance exception was thrown but the cv::Exception wasn't, or that for some reason the cv::Exception isn't being caught?

Also, I'm new to Visual Studio and my C++ is over 10 years rusty (I've been Netbeans and Java mostly since 2000).

Comment: Debug mode adds more checks. There's probably some undefined behavior called in your code. Nevertheless UB might let you feel it's actually working (that's one of it's natures, it can appear woithout significant side effects upon your working code).

Comment: "...doesn't look fatal,..." - fyi the messaging is telling you there is no `catch` handler for that `cv::Exception` type, Thus is **is** fatal. It is throwing all the way out of `main` and into the default abort-handler. Run it in debug and turn **on** break-on-C++ exceptions in the debugger options of Visual Studio. When it is thrown, it should break immediately and show you where.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig. I found where (the line I included). I'll include a catch for the exception; I was leaving it out because this is only sort of one-time code and I haven't dealt with exceptions in C++ before. I meant it didn't look fatal because it continued to run in release.

Comment: The real mystery for me was that this is the exact same code that run fine in both modes before, but now won't in debug. I thought I might have turned on some Visual Studio setting by accident. Thanks both of you for such quick comments.

Comment: OK, I have "fixed" it. I'm not making this an answer, because I'm not confident it is a good one. There is a setting in Visual Studio which allows you to tick break when this exception is thrown. It then breaks on that line. I un-tick, and it just goes on. I've tried exception handling; see my edited question.

Comment: A first-chance exception can be normal. They are for debuggers the allow the debugger alter how an exception is processed. They are meant to occur before the catch block as one of the purposes is to allow the debugger to ignore the exception and not enter the catch block.

Comment: Thanks Steve. So to make sure I'm clear, does this mean that the cv::Exception itself is not being thrown, or are you saying it is being thrown but the first-chance exception is allowing the debugger to jump over the catch block? The syntax of exception handling in C++ is about the same as Java, but it works quite differently under the hood it appears.